# Yahoo Finance API for Headlines with JSON Results

Tags: json, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I just need headlines for a given ticker symbol in JSON format. YQL Console used to have a working [example here](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fq%3Fs%3Dyhoo'%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40id%3D%22yfi_headlines%22%5D%2Fdiv%5B2%5D%2Ful%2Fli%2Fa'), but it seems to be broken now. This is from the console page, "example queries" on the right hand side there is an "Extract headlines from Yahoo Finance" link. This would have been perfect!

Does anyone know how to get this info in json format?

**Edit: Yahoo Pipes has been shut down, so be warned that this answer is no longer valid.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone [created a Yahoo Pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=2FV68p9G3BGVbc7IdLq02Q) to convert RSS to JSON. You can simply pump [Yahoo Finance's company RSS feed](https://developer.yahoo.com/finance/company.html) through that, I guess.

Here's the resulting URL:

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=2FV68p9G3BGVbc7IdLq02Q&_render=json&feedcount=10&feedurl=http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Frss%2Fheadline%3Fs%3Dyhoo

Obviously just change the "yhoo" at the end to whatever stock symbol you're interested in.

Comment: Do you know what the _id field in the pipe URL is? Is that someone's Yahoo account id, which may stop working if too many people use it?

Comment: I am pretty sure that's the ID of which pipe you want to run (in our case, we want to run the Pipe that converts RSS to JSON). I don't know of any usage limitations.